# How to CreateView (generic) item in generic Album - issue with url directions

Tags: python, django, url, generics, view

I have problems with generic Views. I trying Create form to add foto to albums but when I testing my app by trying add some foto it redirect me to create Album (It suppose to create Foto). Why it hapening and what is the solution? (maybe generic is not the best way to do such displays?) some clues? Thanks!

Ps. i notice that it get right url but then goes to "views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail' " not to right one "views.FotoCreate.as_view, name='foto-add' "

-This is from detail html:

```
<a href="{% url 'albumbum:foto-add' album.pk %}" class="btn btn-default active" role="button">
<span class="fa fa-plus fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Dodaj element do albumu</a>
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
# /albumbum/
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

# /albumbum/<albumbum.id>/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

# /albumbum/add/
url(r'add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='add'),

# /albumbum/albumbum/2/
url(r'albumbum/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='albumbum-update'),

# /albumbum/albumbum/2/delete
url(r'albumbum/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='albumbum-delete'),

# /albumbum/2/add
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add/$', views.FotoCreate.as_view, name='foto-add'),
```

-Models

```
class Album(models.Model):
    autor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    nazwa_albumu = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    temat = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    opis_albumu = models.CharField(max_length=700, default="abc")
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_albumu + ' - ' + self.autor


class Foto(models.Model):
    albumnr = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nazwa_foto = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='abc')
    obraz = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='abc')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_foto
```

And Views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .models import Album, Foto

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'albumbum/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'albumbum/detail.html'

class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['autor', 'nazwa_albumu', 'temat', 'album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['autor', 'nazwa_albumu', 'temat', 'album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('albumbum:index')

class FotoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Foto
    fields = ['nazwa_foto', 'obraz']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        album = Foto.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        form.instance.album = album
        return super(FotoCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.I changed a little bit urls paths and it start working properly. I still don't know why before was not working but now it works so  for me its not much important. Solution below:

```
urlpatterns = [
# /albumbum/
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

# /albumbum/<albumbum.id>/
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

# /albumbum/add/
url(r'albumadd/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

# /albumbum/albumbum/2/
url(r'albumbum/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='albumbum-update'),

# /albumbum/albumbum/2/delete
url(r'albumbum/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='albumbum-delete'),

# /albumbum/2/add
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/fotoadd/$', views.FotoCreate.as_view(), name='foto-add'),

 ]
```

Thanks me!